# Discord.py related stuff

Tags: python, discord.py

when i try to create a command with "help" in it; it gives me an error
so for example,

```
@client.command()
async def help():
    print("this works :)")
```

if i create a command called "help" it gives an error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\School Club Discord bot\main.py", line 12, in 
async def help():
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1263, in decorator
self.add_command(result)
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1149, in add_command
raise CommandRegistrationError(command.name)
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandRegistrationError: The command help is already an existing command or alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discord.py already has a built-in help function. you can change it like this:

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', help_command=None)

@client.command()
async def help():
    print("this works :)")
```

If you don't set `help_command=None` and try to create your help command it will default to the built-in command and it will use that instead.

Comment: Don't forget to also include `ctx`, or else an error will be raised.